# Mozilla Firebox version bug

Tags: javascript, browser

Single quote in URL are not work in Firefox version 43 but it work in 41 version. Is there any solution how to pass the single quote in URL?
I use `encodeURIComponent` also but it not work and all replacing technic (%27).

Comment: Given both v41 and v43 are out of support (current ESR is V52) you will have to work around the issue. Please start by defining (with a [re-create](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) "not work": what are you doing, what do you expect to happen and what actually happens.

Comment: when i m using single quote in URL it gives me error "out of ascii range"

Comment: "it gives me": what gives that error: you need to be specific. Best way to get help is to include re-create *in the question*.